# Sorting results based on current year sales in multi-year table and creating rank column SSRS

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, ranking

I am newish to SSRS and I am trying to create a report where where each row displays sales for the selected year and the previous 2 years in separate columns. I would like to sort the results by the current year's sales and create a rank column and create a parameter allowing the user to choose the top N rows they wish to display. I see the tablix sorting tab which allows you to select an expression to sort by, but how would I specify that I want to sort by the sales for one year specifically? Or would I go about this by creating the rank column by that expression first then sorting the table by that rank column?

UPDATE: It is a SQL Server database and I can edit the SQL. For the columns I have storeID, storeName, Year, and Sales.

Comment: What is your dataset definition?  Can you edit the SQL within this dataset?  If so, what does your underlying data look like?  This seems like a very straightforward report but if you don't give us any information we can't really help you.

Comment: It is a SQL Server database and I can edit the SQL. For the columns I have storeID, storeName, Year, and Sales.

Comment: Can you please add some representative dummy data to your question, ideally in a `create table` and `insert` script?